# Show that all the roots of $p(z)= z^5 – z^3 + 1$ are in the ring $\frac{1}{2}\lt \vert z \vert \lt \frac{3}{2}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots, rouches-theorem

I am going to try check that $\vert z^5 – z^3\vert \lt 1$ for $\vert z \vert \le \frac{1}{2}.$

$1=|-1|=|z^5+z^3|=|z|^3\cdot |z^2+1|\le |z^2+1|\le |z|^2+|1|=|z|^2+1  \le 1.$

Now I'm stuck. What do I do next?

Thank's for any help.

Comment: You've misprint $z^5+z^3$  instead of $z^5-z^3$; $|z|^3\cdot|z^2-1|\leq \frac18 \cdot (1+\frac{1}{4})=\frac{5}{32} < 1$.

Comment: The word "annulus" is often used to describe a region between two concentric circles. "Ring" in mathematics can be used for other kinds of things.

Comment: **Hint:** [Rouche’s Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouché%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the triangle inequality,  we get:
$|z^5-z^3|=|z^3||z^2-1|\le\dfrac 18|z^2-1|\le\dfrac 18(|z^2|+1)\le\dfrac 18\left(\dfrac 14+1\right)=\dfrac 18\cdot \dfrac 54=\dfrac 5{32}\lt1$ for $|z|\le\dfrac 12$

Now let $g(z)=z^5$.  Since $|z^3-1|\le|z^3|+1\le\dfrac {27}8+1=\dfrac {35}8\lt|z^5|=\left(\dfrac 32\right)^5$, on $|z|=\dfrac 32$, by Rouche we get that there are $5$ zeros in the given annulus.

Comment: `\mid` is a neat command that generates nice spaces that are useful for certain things, like writing conditional probability e.g $\Pr(X>8 \mid Y<5)$ but when writing equations that contain a lot of absolute value signs, a simple `|` is far better.

Comment: Okay,  I see what you mean.   @K.defaoite

Comment: @K.defaoite Actually, use `\lvert` an `\rvert` for absolute value delimiters. Try both methods for the absolute value of $-1$ to see why.

Comment: @WimC Good point. But usually I find this is more trouble than it's worth for anything except my own academic work.